# Magento 2.3.2 - Last 5 orders on Dashboard showing empty on total column after migrating database from osCommerce

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento2-migration-tool

I am facing issues on the dashboard at the Last Orders section, as the total column is showing empty.
The same code is running on my local server without any issue, but not working on the live server after migrating the database from osCommerce.

blow is the snapshot of the issue:

[image]

Please suggest a way to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you set the magento crons?

Comment: Actually it is working fine on the local server, but on live it creating problem after migrating the database from osCommerce using the LiteExtention migration tool